# Insert and update db using one button

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

I want to use one button to do two different functions, to insert into MS SQL db and to update db using one save button.

Comment: buttons can only submit the form, you have to write your logic to do the two.

Comment: ok but after inserting u want to update diff table of same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting what you want to say, you can achieve this using javascript function and onClick event.

Lets take an example of user management, i.e., inserting and updating user. When you are inserting a user, the `$user_id` will be empty or say `$_REQUEST['user_id']` will not set.
When you are updating a user, `$_REQUEST['user_id']` will contain the id of the user to be updated.
So considering this as a condition,

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="command" value="Perform Action" 
onclick="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['user_id'])) 
echo 'return OnButton1();' else echo 'return OnButton2();'; ?>">
```

and the functions `OnButton1()` and `OnButton2()` will contain the actions of the form to submit.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function OnButton1()
    {
        document.formUser.action = "edit_user.php"
        document.formUser.submit();
        return true;
    }

    function OnButton2()
    {
        document.formEditUser.action = "add_user.php"
        document.formEditUser.submit();
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Thus, **single button to perform two actions**

Comment: I have a three inputs and three buttons. add button, edit button and save button. if i click on add, i will be able to add to the database and if i click on the edit, the first input changes to a drop-down and brings all that has being  added. Now what i want is a situation where the save button insert a new user input into the database or select and edit from the drop-down list then clicks the save button to update the edited information

Comment: Now this situation totally differs from what you have mentioned in your question........!!! BE SPECIFIC WHILE ASKING QUESTION!

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form,

First insert the values to required table, if the insertion is success, then call update query.

```
insert code here
if(successful insertion){
{
     //update code here
} else {
     // some error occurred
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form :

Do a request like this to see if the line doesn't already exist in your database.

```
$SQL = "SELECT  something  FROM  your db  WHERE  your inputed data";
```

Then when you test this request based on the result, you do an UPDATE or a INSERT INTO.

//True  = Already exist = Update

//False = Doesn't exist = Insert Into

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$SQL){
  // update
}else{
 // insert
}
```